# open the same wav file give me a javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException

Tags: java, javasound, clip

i have two similar wave (similar format) and I preload them with this code

```
Clip click1;
Clip click2;

File soundFile = new File("click1.wav");
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
click1 = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
click1.open(sound);

soundFile = new File("click2.wav");
sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
click2 = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
click2.open(sound);
```

The first file is load, but the second throw an exception:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:492)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:1278)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:107)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1059)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1149)
```

I've tried to set click1.wav on click2's clips and I have the same error.

I have Ubuntu 11.04 and this is the result of java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode
```

**edit**

This is the result of the System.out.println of the DataLine.Info

click1 = interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED 11025.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian

click2 = interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED 11025.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian

Answer (score 0):

Two trouble-shooting ideas:

1) Switch the files. Does the error switch to the first load? If not, then the problem is probably due to the next suggestion.

2) Don't try to reuse 'info' or 'sound', make new variables.

Which line does the error occur on? I don't think Java lets you reuse the sound variables. I'm unclear of the reasons why. I just remember when I tried to reuse variables, I had to go all the way back to the 'soundFile' variable before Java would let me do so.

Comment: thank you, but I have tried to use new variable and I have the same problem.

Comment: Are you using entirely different variables for the AudioInputStream 'sound', the 'info' variable AND 'soundFile'? It would be helpful to see how you implement this if it isn't working.

Comment: I've upgraded to Java 7 and I solved the problem. However, I had used different variables for "sound", "info" and "soundFile".